# 7zip files do not have icons

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder, icon, ventura

For some unknown reason, the .7zip files do not have an icon on my MacBook Air. I'm not even able to change it from the "info" window. that "blank" spot is not even clickable whenever I try to select the file.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to fix it?

[image: 7zip file icon not displayed example and file info panel]

I am on a MacBook Air M1 2020 running macOS Ventura 13.3.1, I have a 8GB memory.

Comment: Which app opens those files?

Comment: The default "archive utility"